# Admin users not able to see non English assets

Tags: media-library

We are using Sitecore 9.1, SXA 1.7.1 and it is multi Site architecture  (English and Italian Sites).As a Admin user when i am setting up an content for Italian site, by default the assets are mapped to English language in Media Library and I am not able to view them in content item.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Ajur D K

Comment: Are you uploading your assets as versioned or unversioned?

Comment: Hi Richard, I am uploading assets as versioned.

Comment: Have you added an Italian version to the media item?

Comment: Yes, I have added Italian version in media item.